# openshift: enable execution of cgi scripts

Tags: cgi, openshift

I have configured .htaccess file under  $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/cgi-bin to enable execution of cgi scripts.

AddHandler perl-script .pl 
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI

But when I open the cgi script on browser, it just shows the script.
The server is not enabled to execute cgi scripts.

PS: My cgi script has execute permissions. I have restarted my openshift application as well.

Comment: What cartridges are you using on OpenShift? Perl, PHP, Python, Java, etc?

Comment: I have included only mysql cartridge. Openshift by default provides all interpreters. So no need to add Perl/python manually. BTW I'm using Perl cgi scripts

Comment: What web cartridge are you using? PHP? Perl? etc?

Comment: I'm using Perl as web catridge